# Why do I have permission to push to a newly created gitlab project?

Tags: git, permissions, gitlab

I have a private gitlab server. And I just created a new project named `TestCreateProject` inside a group named `Foo`. The project is created using the root account.

The project's [visibility level](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/public_access/public_access.html) is *private*.

[image]

And it has no members:

[image]

I'm wondering why I can clone from and push to the project. I mean I can run the following commands without any problem:

```
git clone http://mygitlab.com/root/testcreateproject.git
cd testcreateproject
touch README.md
git add README.md
git commit -m "add README"
git push -u origin master
```

The `git config --list` command tells me that my current `user.name` and `user.email` does not exist on my private gitlab server.

The history shows that my `user.name` authored the commit 27 minutes ago.

[image]

Why didn't I got rejected when cloning from and pushing to the project?

The version of my community edition gitlab is `11.10.0`.

My git version is `git version 2.17.2 (Apple Git-113)`

---

------------------------------------ Edit ------------------------------------

I found that the project actually contains 1 member by visiting `Settings` -> `Members` in the project

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`git config --list` shows that my `credential.helper` is `osxkeychain`.

So I open the *Keychain Access* app in my MacOS to check if the root account's user name and password are stored there.

Then I found the user name and password of the root account are really stored in *Keychain Access*.

This means that git uses the information stored in *Keychain Access* to pull from and push to the project.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as a repository without members. There is at least the owner — the one who has created the repo or the one who's got the repo transferred from the previous owner.

As the owner you can do anything with the repository — clone, pull, push. See https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/permissions.html

Comment: But the `user.name` shown by `git config --list` is different from the root account of the gitlab server. Why can I still push to the project?

Comment: `user.name`/`user.email` have absolutely nothing with authentication. They are only used to create commits. Authentication for protocol `http://` is performed separately.